# Graph - cannot find min route to node

Tags: c#, graph, graph-traversal

I want to find route with min cost to node.
It finds me several routes but there are not routes with min cost.

My class to store information about nodes:

```
public class Graph
{
    //public int[][] childNodes;
    //public Graph(int[][] nodes)
    //{
    //    this.childNodes = nodes;
    //}

    public List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
}

public class Node
{
    public Node(int node)
    {
        this.node = node;
    }

    public int node { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<int,int>> endNodes = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
}

public class Routes
{
    public int depth { get; set; }
    public int cost { get; set; }
    public List<string> nodes = new List<string>();
}
```

In tuple I have int, int - first int is end node, second int is cost of route to this node

Class to traverse graph:

```
public List<string> visited = new List<string>();
public List<Routes> routes = new List<Routes>();





   public void dfs2(Node node, List<Routes> routes, Routes route, int depth)
        {
            depth++;
            foreach (Tuple<int,int> childNode in g.nodes[node.node].endNodes)
            {
                string path = string.Format("{0}{1}", node.node, childNode.Item1);
                string pathReverse = string.Format("{0}{1}", childNode.Item1, node.node);
               // if (!visited.Contains(path)) // && !visited.Contains(pathReverse))
                if(!route.nodes.Contains(path)) // && !route.nodes.Contains(pathReverse))
                {
                    visited.Add(path);
                    if (childNode.Item1 == 6)
                    {
                        Routes newRoutes = new Routes();
                        newRoutes.depth = depth;
                        newRoutes.cost = route.cost + childNode.Item2;
                        newRoutes.nodes.AddRange(route.nodes);
                        newRoutes.nodes.Add(path);
                        routes.Add(newRoutes);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        route.depth = depth;
                        route.cost += childNode.Item2; // 2;//childNode.
                        route.nodes.Add(path);

                        dfs2(g.nodes[childNode.Item1], routes, route, depth);
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine("przeszedłem: " + path);

                }
            }
        }
```

In my example I want to find route with min cost to node 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a concise-but-complete code example, it's hard to provide a good answer. In your question, I didn't even see any example graph data to work with, never mind a clear description of what happens and what you'd like to happen instead.

That said, you may be interested in studying a classic path-finding algorithm and its relatives:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

The basic idea in that algorithm is that for each edge in the graph, you need a cost value, and for each node, you need a way to estimate the remaining cost to the destination. Note that the "remaining cost" estimate can be set to 0, which will result in a breath-first search of all paths…slow, but it would still produce a correct result (assuming your graph is small enough that the algorithm can complete in a useful amount of time). It is better if your data is conducive to calculating good estimates.

The algorithm works by keeping track of the cost to the current node, and selecting an adjacent node where the current cost, plus the cost to the adjacent node, plus the estimated cost from that node to the destination, is minimized. A sorted list of nodes by total cost (cost to that node plus estimated cost) is maintained so that at each iteration, one can always select the least-cost node. If and when the current path-plus-estimate becomes more expensive than the path-plus-estimate for some other visited node, the algorithm effectively backtracks to that less-expensive node and continues from there.

Essentially, it's exploring the graph, pursuing the paths that appear to have the least cost based on an educated guess of distance remaining. The performance of the algorithm will depend on how well you can implement that "educated guess".